# Hot key for indentation multiple rows in Dbeaver

Tags: indentation, dbeaver

Which hotkey to use in DBeaver to indent from this:

```
SELECT 
    column1,
    column2
FROM table1
```

to this:

```
    SELECT
        column1,
        column2
    FROM table1
```

Comment: Usually `Ctrl + ]`

Comment: In DBeaver this combination just opens new script empty page, nothing common to indentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mark several lines of code with your mouse and press Tab on your keyboard

Comment: Is there any way of unindenting the code?

Answer (score 3):

Besides @discipulus answer; if you needed to indent more than or less than standard size indent use multiple line change. For multiple line changes (selection, insertion, deletion or updation). You can press

1. alt+shift+a
2. shift+down arrow
3. insert or delete text etc.
4. To relinquish multiple selection press again alt+shift+a